# manually set time using a code

Tags: android, time, clock

Hi I am interested in a code that can be used to manually set time. I hear setting system is not possible because of license issues. But what I am interested in is the display time, which a user is allowed to manually set. Only difference is now I want an app to do it. How can I do it? thanks. kiran prakash

Answer (score 1):

You can not change system time/date through your application. This operation requires a special use-permission (`SET_TIME`) granted only to applications that are in the Android system image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I want an app that can set the time faster than the actual time. I choose 10 min, and it will do the function of set time manually (that i could have done directly without the app). So no way an app can do it in android, ha? At least on IOS? Okie dokie.

Comment: The only thing you can do in android is start a particular intent the will open the settings.

Comment: Ok. open the settings, and probably read them, but not change them is it? Sorry for asking in such detail. I am new to android. I appreciate ur help